Chrome Protocol Handler (OSX)
I have been successfully using a custom protocol to launch a local app through Chrome, but as of the latest Chrome update (130.0.6723.59) it is no longer working.
A button on a website sends the URL and Chrome would previously prompt the user to open the app (like the screenshot below):

Now, there is just a spinning wheel with no option to open the app.
Going to the the handlers settings in Chrome (chrome://settings/handlers), I can confirm that "Sites can ask to handle protocols" is selected:

Any advice on Chrome settings adjustments to fix this?

have you try encodeURIComponent url?

We ran into this same issue where suddenly chrome protocol stopped working correctly, but Edge still worked fine with it.  What we found is that our protocol was sending a set of parameters such as the following:
MyProtocolHandler://value1=test&valueURL=http://myService.com/service.asmx&valueName=Test
What we found is that chrome would wipe out the colon that was in the valueURL reading the string as the following:
MyProtocolHandler://value1=test&valueURL=http//myService.com/service.asmx&valueName=Test
The corruption of the URL in the set of values caused our program to fail to run correctly.  The solution is likely related to maxisam comment asking if you encoded the URL.  In our case, encoding the URL value for that parameter appears to have worked correctly.
